# DocumentRoot and Directory - necessary outside of VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache-2.4

The default config had the following in the root:

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Is it correctly understood that this is only used if server is reached using it's IP address directly?

In my case, the server will only be reached by domain names, using VirtualHost. In other words, I should just remove both the Directory and DocumentRoot located outside VirtualHosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most directives in the main server configuration - that is, outside of any `VirtualHost` container - are inherited by the virtual hosts. So your configuration becomes the default for all of your virtual hosts, unless you override it within them. This is sort of described in [How the sections are merged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging).

An exception is rewrite rules, which aren't inherited unless you set `RewriteOptions Inherit`. See [RewriteOptions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions).